# Higcharts - timeline series type- continuous color with datetime x axis

Tags: highcharts, flags, timeline

i would like to have something like a 'timeline' chart with a label/tooltip mixed with other series type like 'line'.
 I have a datatipe like a 'flag' that is very repetitive so I would like to "extend the flag for the same value". 
So I suppose 'timeline' series type BUT when the x axis is setted as 'datetime' the timeline series stopped to be a bar and begin to be a "point".
But with 'timeline' and  x axis setted as 'datetime' the rectangle are not sized in a continuous way.

I would like something like this (as you can see I'm not a grafic designer)
[image: desired]

but this is what I obtain
[image]

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `xrange` series:

```
  series: [{
    type: 'line',
    data: [...]
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    data: [...]
  }, {
    type: 'xrange',
    data: [...]
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5hkcLn7v/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/x-range-series

Answer (score 0):

A work colleague of mine passed by me and suggests to use "plotbands". I think I'll take this road.
[image]

Comment: It's kinda workaround but it can do the job i think